# Springboot how to get location of jars under web-inf/lib folder to configure classpath

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have 1 requirement which uses the "java" command using JAVA_HOME in side springboot project. while calling the java command it requires the jars which are available under WEB-INF/lib folder of springboot war. I want to list all the jars inside a variable so that i can pass this varible as an argument to java command.

How can i configure the classpath to list all the jars of WEB-INF/lib folder????

Comment: When needing to do this you are probably already fixing the wrong problem.  Spring Boot creates an executable jar or war which can be run with doing `java -jar your.[jar|war]` you don't need to include the libraries on the classpath that will be figured out for you.

Comment: Let me reiterate in another way  :  forget springboot, i just want to run a java program in which i am using some jars which are available i 1 war file(springboot war), so i want to keep those jars in classpath. 
I am able to keep jars of normal war file in classpath during runtime but how can we keep jars in classpath of springboot.